# Laravel 5 route mix

Tags: laravel

i have for example the following routes:

```
Route::get('/adres/{postcode}/{housenumber}/{letter?}/{additional?}/what', 'AaaController@aaa');
/adres/1234aa/1/what
/adres/1234aa/2/A/what
/adres/1234aa/3/B/additional/what

Route::get('/adres/{postcode}/{housenumber}/{letter?}/{additional?}', 'AaaController@bbb');
/adres/1234aa/3/B/additional/
```

So if i enter

```
www.domain.com/adres/1111aa/1/what
```

it doesn't get the second route.

How can i achieve that?

Comment: You've got two routes starting with /adres/
You are trying to access /1111aa/1/what  which isn't starting with /adres/ so it's normal taht you can't reach any route

Answer (score 0):

you have to add **/adres/** to your url 
*from*

```
www.domain.com/1111aa/1/what
```

*to*

```
www.domain.com/adres/1111aa/1/what
```

Comment: Sorry, the url wasnt good, its www.domain.com/adres/1111aa/1/what